# Running symfony3 on Openshift, composer not found

Tags: composer-php, openshift, symfony

I recently discover [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com) and look exactly what I needed. Now I'm trying to running a simple symfony3 project on it. I create an application with [this cartridge](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/232-php5-5-cgi-apache)  (since I need php 5.5), successfully installed after waiting some minutes ,and then upload a symfony project from my local laptop  to the created www folder. Now I'm lost on how to activate composer to install and update vendors.

I read this [link](https://developers.openshift.com/languages/php/markers.html), and as it say I create an empty file called use_composer in the marker folder. Then I login with a putty client, go to my project folder(app-root/runtime/repo/www/symfony/), but executing composer install on it give me 'composer: command not found'. I'm sorry if it's a newbie question, but in fact I'm not a linux user. Maybe I need to restart the application or something. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an answer from [this article](http://www.deploy2cloud.com/laravel/Install-Custom-laravel-4-Application-to-OpenShift)

1. Execute `curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --quiet --install-dir=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`
2. Now you can call composer like this `php $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar update`